# Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to implement a chart in my React project using chart.js. Even though I correctly coded , I was unable to render the chart.

I get the following error and I tried many ways but it still shows the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.
    at new Chart (chart.mjs:5428:1)
    at renderChart (chart.tsx:42:1)
    at chart.tsx:98:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:22910:1)
    at invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:24923:1)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27122:1)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27101:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:26812:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26736:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26689:1)
```

So here is my DoughnutChart.js component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    },
  ],
};

function DoughnutChart() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Doughnut Chart</h1>
      <Doughnut data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DoughnutChart;
```

And here is my App.js file

```
import './App.css';
import DoughnutChart from './charts/DoughnutChart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DoughnutChart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone help me in this case ? Thank you in advance!